# Weird print from simple program

Tags: c

I'm creating a program where I ask the user to enter some of his personal informations, but for some reason I can't figure it out. When I ask the user to enter his birth date and his email, the message appears in a weird way for the user.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX  50
char name[MAX],date[MAX],email[MAX],cpf[MAX],tel[MAX],contatip[MAX],esc3[MAX],esc4[MAX];

int main()
{
    printf("\nEnter your name: ");
        scanf("%s",name);
    printf("\nBirth date:"); // The problem is here
        gets(date);
    printf("\Email: ");
        gets(email);
    printf("\nEnter your CPF: ");
        gets(cpf);
    printf("\nCelphone: ");
        gets(tel);
}
```

Comment: "appears in a weird way". What does that mean? Please show the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: OT: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used). Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: `scanf("%s",name);` reads until whitespace is encountered so if you enter a first and last name then the last name will go into the birth date.  If you even enter a first name and then press space and then enter the scanf will stop after the first name and leave the enter key in the buffer and the birth date will be empty.  You need to use fgets() for all the entries.

Comment: you might want to add `fflush()` after every `printf` before `fgets`.

Comment: Here is an example of scanf leaving stuff in the buffer: https://onlinegdb.com/5DyozWDn7

Comment: Don't use `gets`.  It is no longer supported, and hopefully won't even exist at some point.  The man page should explain this.  Use `fgets` instead.  And change the `scanf` to `fgets` as well.

Comment: @Serge you do not need `fflush()`, when an input function such as `fgets()` or `scanf()` is invoked, output streams are flushed.

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-with-scanf-when-there-is-fgetsgetsscanf-after-it/) article. As others said, use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 50

char name[MAX], date[MAX], email[MAX], cpf[MAX], tel[MAX], contatip[MAX], esc3[MAX], esc4[MAX];

int main()
{
    printf("\nEnter your name: ");
        fgets(name, MAX, stdin);
    printf("\nBirth date: ");
        fgets(date, MAX, stdin);
    printf("\nEmail: ");
        fgets(email, MAX, stdin);
    printf("\nEnter your CPF: ");
        fgets(cpf, MAX, stdin);
    printf("\nCellphone: ");
        fgets(tel, MAX, stdin);
    // printf("\n%s", name);
    // printf("%s", date);
    // printf("%s", email);
    // printf("%s", cpf);
    // printf("%s", tel);
}
```